# Laravel attach() method not working to hasMany side

Tags: php, laravel-4

The application has the models:

#### Atividade.php

```php
class Atividade extends Eloquent {
    public function intervencoes() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Intervencao');
    }
}
```

#### Intervencao.php

```php
class Intervencao extends Eloquent {
    public function atividades() {
        return $this->hasMany('Atividade');
    }
}
```

The following code works:

```php
Atividade::find($id)->intervencoes()->attach($intervencao_id);
```

But, this...

```php
Intervencao::find($id)->atividades()->attach($atividade_id);
```

Returns an BadMethodCallException:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::attach()

#### SOLUTION (thanks to @gnack):

I was trying to set a many-to-many relationship, so just needed to change this...

```php
return $this->hasMany('Atividade');
```

To this:

```php
return $this->belongsToMany('Atividade');
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

See the Laravel documentation here:
http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#inserting-related-models

Basically you have set up two different types of relationships for the same two tables - you've set up a many-to-many and a one-to-many.  It looks as though you probably wanted a many-to-many, so you'll need to change this line:

```
return $this->hasMany('Atividade');
```

To this:

```
return $this->belongsToMany('Atividade');
```

This will set the relationship up as a many-to-many relationship, which will then support the `attach()` method.

The `attach()` method is only for many-to-many, for other relationships there's `save()` or `saveMany()` and `associate()` (see the docs linked above).

Comment: Yeah, i get confused. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

See the documentation Laravel 5.7

*A Comment belongTo an unique Post*

```
class Comment extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the post that owns the comment.
     */
    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
    }
}
```

*A Post can Have multiple Comments*

```
class Post extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the comments for the blog post.
     */
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
    }
```

When you want to update/delete a belongsTo relationship, you may use the associate/dissociate method.

```
$post= App\Post::find(10);
$comment= App\Comment::find(3);
$comment->post()->associate($post); //update the model

$comment->save(); //you have to call save() method

//delete operation
$comment->post()->dissociate(); 

$comment->save(); //save() method
```

Answer (score 2):

`attach()` is for many-to-many relationships.  It seems your relationship is supposed to be a many-to-many but you have not set it up correctly for that.

```
class Intervencao extends Eloquent {
    public function atividades() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Atividade');
    }
}
```

Then the `attach()` should work

Answer (score 0):

In my case I've two roles() methods that's why it's throwing this error.