# Trying to fill the intermediate table using attach() but getting "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::attach()"

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have tables called `users`, `places` and `user_place`. `users` has a column called `id` that contains the id of the user and places has a column called `place_id` as well. The `user_place` table has 2 columns called `user_id` and `place_id` and I'm trying to automatically populate them with the corresponding ids. I read I have to use attach() function after setting up the relationships which I believe I have done but I might be wrong. Here they are:

```
class PlaceController extends Controller
{
    public function likePlace(Request $request){
        $placeId = $request['placeId'];
        $userId = $request['userId'];
        $user = User::where('id', $userId)->first();

        $place = new Place();
        $place->place_id = $placeId;
        $place->save();

        $user->places()->attach($place);
    }
}
```

User model:

```
class User extends \Eloquent implements Authenticatable
{
    use AuthenticableTrait;

    public function places(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Place');
    }
}
```

Place mode:

```
class Place extends Model
{
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this your case? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21566705/laravel-attach-method-not-working-to-hasmany-side

Comment: I did check that post but it didn't help as I've already done the solution to it.

Comment: `attach` is part of [belongsToMany](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsToMany.html), not [hasMany](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasMany.html) (or [HasOneOrMany](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasOneOrMany.html), which HasMany extends)

Comment: @Bobimaru I've added some tips at the end of my response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a [Many to Many relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many), you should define both relationships like the following:

**User.php**

```
class User extends \Eloquent implements Authenticatable
{
    use AuthenticableTrait;

    public function places()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Place', 'user_place', 'user_id', 'place_id');
    }   //                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

Note: Given that your intermetiate table name doesn't follow the [naming convention](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions) we specified so Laravel knows where table to look up.

**Place.php**

Notice that you mentioned that the primmary key of your Place model is `place_id`, and this also scapes from the [Laravel convention](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions) you should specify it:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'place_id'; // <----

class Place extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'user_place', 'place_id', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

So now in your controller:

```
class PlaceController extends Controller
{
    public function likePlace(Request $request)
    {
        $placeId = $request['placeId'];
        $userId = $request['userId'];

        $user = User::where('id', $userId)->first();

        $place = new Place();
        $place->place_id = $placeId;
        $place->save();

        $user->places()->attach($place);
    }
}
```

---

### Side note

As I side note, you could save a couple of line replacing some sentences with their equivalent:

```
    $userId = $request['userId'];
    $user = User::where('id', $userId)->first();
```

Using the [find()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-collections#available-methods) method, this is equal to:

```
    $user = User::find($request['userId']);
```

Then, you could create your related object using the static method `create` of an Eloquent model so this:

```
    $placeId = $request['placeId'];
    $place = new Place();
    $place->place_id = $placeId;
    $place->save();
```

Is equal to this:

```
    $place = Place::create(['place_id' => $request['placeId']]);
```

Then your controller will be reduced to this:

```
class PlaceController extends Controller
{
    public function likePlace(Request $request)
    {

        $user = User::find($request['userId']);
        $place = Place::create(['place_id' => $request['placeId']]);

        $user->places()->attach($place);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the help. Just out of curiosity, how should my user_place table be called in order to follow convention?

Comment: It is placed in the [Many to Many section](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) of the docs. It says: `The  pivot table is derived from the alphabetical order of the related model names`. So in your case: `place_user`. Give the docs a try, are very user friendly and it is very easy to navigate.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that.