# Call to undefined method BelongsTo::attach()

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Why isn't the relationship working?

I am trying to relate post and categories using laravel 5.2, mysql, migrations and seeders.

but I get an error:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::attach()

`PostTableSeeder.php`

```
public function run()
{
    factory(App\Post::class, 300)->create()->each(function (App\Post $post) {
        $post->category()->attach([
            rand(1, 5),
            rand(6, 14),
            rand(15, 20),

        ]);
    });
}
```

MODEL: `Post.php`

```
public function category()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}
```

MODEL: `Category.php`

```
public function posts()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
}
```

Comment: I think if you want to attach many categories to a post you need to define the relation as belongsToMany instead belongsTo

Comment: Is not clear to me what belongs to what, can you please add in the question the relevant tables fields?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define a `belongsToMany` relationship in your model

```php
public function category()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
}
```

Don't forget to add an intermediate pivot table for `Post` and `Category` association

Since you don't RTFM, here's a full working example

`PostTableSeeder.php`

```php
public function run()
{
    factory(App\Post::class, 300)->create()->each(function (App\Post $post) {
        $post->categories()->attach([
            rand(1, 5),
            rand(6, 14),
            rand(15, 20),
        ]);
    });
}
```

`Post.php` model

```php
public function categories()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category');
}
```

`Category.php` model

```php
public function posts()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category');
}
```

`category_post` table migration

```php
Schema::create('category_post', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('post_id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id');
});
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, I added belongsToMany in the Post model
```
public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class); //post pertenece a una categoria
    }
```
But the results is 
```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'category_id' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `category_post` (`category_id`, `post_id`) values (4, 1), (6, 1), (19, 1))```

Comment: Hmm. Shouldn't there be a `has...` side and a `belongsTo...` side? Was also wondering about what @Caddy DZ suggested after reading:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21566705/laravel-attach-method-not-working-to-hasmany-side/21566764

Comment: Without the tables it could be also a hasMany with a belongsTo like @ficuscr suggested I don't understand yet where could be the foreign key

Comment: The OP didn't post the tables @porloscerros-Ψ, any assumption could be wrong.

Comment: Work perfect! perfect!
I am a rookie in Laravel and spent 6 hours trying to solve this. thank you very much friend

Comment: Next time post the tables also, please ;).

Comment: I recommend reading the docs or watching Laracasts (not sponsored) and you won't waste any time trying to discover things yourself